# How to Get Test Coverage for Guard Statement Fall-through

Tags: swift, unit-testing, bdd, guard-statement

I started writing iOS unit tests today with the BDD approach. I have a question regarding `guard` statements and getting to 100% code coverage.

I have the following code, which handles the conversion of `Data` into `Customer` objects.

```swift
internal final class func customer(from data: Data) -> Customer? {
    do {
        guard let jsonDictionary = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? Dictionary<String, Any> else {
            return nil
        }
        var customerFirstName: String? = nil
        var customerLastName: String
        if let firstName = jsonDictionary["first_name"] as? String {
            customerFirstName = firstName
        }
        guard let lastName = jsonDictionary["last_name"] as? String else {
            return nil
        }
        customerLastName = lastName
        return Customer(firstName: customerFirstName, lastName: customerLastName)
    } catch {
        return nil
    }
}
```

When our backend was created, some customers were given just a last name, which contained their first and last names. That is why the customer's first name is optional; their full name may be the value for `last_name`.

In my code, the customer's first name is optional while their last name is required. If their last name is not returned in the received JSON from a network request, then I do not create the customer. Also, if the `Data` cannot be serialized into a `Dictionary`, then the customer is not created.

I have two JSON files, both of which contain customer information that I am using to test both scenarios.

One contains no first name in the JSON:

```swift
{
    "first_name": null,
    "last_name": "Test Name",
}
```

The other contains a first name in the JSON:

```swift
{
    "first_name": "Test",
    "last_name": "Name",
}
```

In my unit test, using Quick and Nimble, I handle the creation of a `Customer` when the first name is not available and when it is:

```swift
override func spec() {
    super.spec()
    let bundle = Bundle(for: type(of: self))
    describe("customer") {
        context("whenAllDataAvailable") {
            it("createsSuccessfully") {
                let path = bundle.path(forResource: "CustomerValidFullName", ofType: "json", inDirectory: "ResponseStubs")!
                let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: path)
                let data = try! Data(contentsOf: url)
                let customer = DataTransformer.customer(from: data)
                expect(customer).toNot(beNil())
            }
        }
        context("whenMissingLastName") {
            it("createsUnsuccessfully") {
                let path = bundle.path(forResource: "CustomerMissingLastName", ofType: "json", inDirectory: "ResponseStubs")!
                let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: path)
                let data = try! Data(contentsOf: url)
                let customer = DataTransformer.customer(from: data)
                expect(customer).to(beNil())
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This ensures that I am creating a `Customer` when the first name is missing or present in the returned JSON.

How can I get to 100% code coverage of this method, using BDD, when my code does not hit the `else` clauses of the `guard` statements since the data is able to be turned into valid JSON objects? Should I just add another `.json` file with data that cannot be transformed into a JSON object to ensure that a `Customer` is not created as well as a `.json` file that contains a missing `last_name` to ensure that a `Customer` is not created?

Am I just over-thinking the "100% code coverage" concept? Do I even need to have the `else` clauses of the `guard` statements tested? Do I even have the appropriate approach using the BDD method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just write whatever JSON you want — malformed in every way you can think of. Examples:

- You can hit your exception-handling with something that isn't correct JSON.
- You can hit your very first `guard` with something that is a JSON array, not a dictionary.

As the saying goes, you only need to cover code that you want to be correct.

TDD and BDD are related. In TDD, you'd write a failing test first. Then, you'd write code that passes that test as quickly as you can. Finally, you'd clean up your code to make it better. It looks like you're adding tests after-the-fact.

By the way, your tests would be much clearer if you didn't use external files, but put the JSON straight into your tests. Here's a screencast showing how I TDD the beginnings of JSON conversion. The screencast is in Objective-C but the principles are the same: https://qualitycoding.org/tdd-json-parsing/

Comment: @JonRein I appreciate your insight! Can I ask, how did you conclude that I wrote my tests after-the-fact? That is exactly what I did, but I'm curious what made you come to that conclusion. I'm definitely studying your concepts and hoping to get a better understanding.

Comment: @NickKohrn Because when code is test-driven, you don't get to write any code that doesn't satisfy a test. So you don't end up asking, "I have some code, now how do I cover it?"

Answer (score 0):

100% code coverage with **if let.**

At times, its not feasible to forcefully prepare a malformed object to enforce the execution hitting `return` or `return nil` used in `guard` statements.

This is the case when you have 3rd party SDKs integrated and respective 3rd party objects get created runtime within the method.
For example :

```
func aMethod() {
   guard let response = 3rdPartyResponse<3rdPartyInput>.createControl(with: .create(with: .someCase)) as? 3rdPartyResponse<3rdPartyInput> else { return }
}
```

In this case, its very hard, at times not possible to hit the return.

**But If code coverage is the *main criteria*, you can go with using an *if let* for such cases** If lets does give 100% code coverage